# Ordering a PriorityQueue by a field of a non-case class

Tags: scala, priority-queue

I'm currently trying to implement the huffman algorithm using scala. To do this, I'd figured I'd use a PriorityQueue for the ordering of the different Nodes in the tree based on their weight. Thus, I have to create a PriorityQueue of BinarySearchTree Nodes. However, Scala only lets me order by a field of a case class.

This is want I want:

```
  class BinarySearchTree(weight: Int)
  case class ForkNode(left: BinarySearchTree, right: BinarySearchTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends BinarySearchTree(weight)
  case class LeafNode(char: Char, weight: Int) extends BinarySearchTree(weight)

  def createBST(inputFile: ListMap[Char,Int]): BinarySearchTree = {
    def weightOrder(t2: BinarySearchTree) = t2.weight
    val nodeMap:PriorityQueue[BinarySearchTree] = PriorityQueue(Ordering.by(weightOrder))
    null
  }
```

But it doesn't compile. However, `def weightOrder(t2: ForkNode) = t2.weight` does compile, but that is not what I want.

How can I order my priority queue based on a field in a non-case class?

Comment: you can either put val befor weight in your class (otherwise weight is just paramter of constructor, not a member), or better to use traits instead of classes

Comment: @dk14 Now that line compiles, but now the nodeMap declaration line gives the compile error found: scala.math.ordering[BinarySearchTree] required: BinarySearchTree... Any idea?

Comment: @SimonBears `PriorityQueue.apply[T](T*)(Ordering[T]): PriorityQueue[T]`. It thinks you're trying to make a `PriorityQueue[Ordering[BinarySearchTree]]` when you call `PriorityQueue.apply(Ordering.by(...))`. I think empty parens might work: `PriorityQueue()(Ordering.by(...))`, but if it doesn't this definitely will: `PriorityQueue.apply(Seq[BinarySearchTree](): _*)(Ordering.by(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incomplete but compiles.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
import collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

class BinarySearchTree(val weight: Int)  //weight is now member data

case class ForkNode( left: BinarySearchTree
                   , right: BinarySearchTree
                   , chars: List[Char]
                   , override val weight: Int  //now needs override
                   ) extends BinarySearchTree(weight)

case class LeafNode( char: Char
                   , override val weight: Int  //now needs override
                   ) extends BinarySearchTree(weight)

def createBST(inputFile: ListMap[Char,Int]): BinarySearchTree = {
  def weightOrder(t2: BinarySearchTree) = t2.weight

  val bst: BinarySearchTree = LeafNode('c',2) //build something of proper type

  val nodeMap:PriorityQueue[BinarySearchTree] =
    PriorityQueue(bst)(Ordering.by(weightOrder))  //create PriorityQueue

  null  //etc.
}
```

`PriorityQueue` is mutable and type invariant so if you want a `PriorityQueue[BinarySearchTree]` then the constructor argument must be of type `BinarySearchTree` and not a derived type (i.e. a Node).

Comment: Do you have to construct it with a LeafNode? Can't the PriorityQueue just be empty on declaration?

Comment: I used `LeafNode()` just as an illustration. It can be `null`. The compiler just has to recognize it as type `BinarySearchTree`.

Comment: If it is null, it would be an empty Priority Queue?

Comment: Yes, but you can also pass an empty parameter: `PriorityQueue()(Ordering.by(weightOrder))`